# PHP Memcache is not able to get keys set by Node js memcached-promisify module

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, memcached

I'm using Node Js [memcached-promisify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached-promisify) module to set some keys to the memory cache.
When I try to get this key using PHP Memcache, I don't get any output.

But when I set the keys using Node Js [memcached](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memcached) module then I'm able to get the key using PHP Memcache.

I'm using memcached-promisify because it solved some of the issues I was facing when using memcached in node js.

I'm not able to figure out why php memcache is not able to get keys set by node js memcached-promisify. I'm I missing any driver?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.

Here is the code:

Node Js:

```
const Cache = require('memcached-promisify');
const cached = new Cache({ 'keyPrefix': 'prefix', 'cacheHost': 'localhost' });
 cached.set('test',JSON.stringify("hi), 0);
```

PHP:

```
 $memcache = new Memcache;
 $memcache->connect('localhost', 11211) or die ("Could not connect");
 $data = $memcache->get("test");
 $a =  json_decode($data,TRUE);
 echo print_r($a); //prints nothing in this case
```

Any suggestions on this would be helpful.

Comment: You didn't share any code on either side, but wild guess - are you dealing with an async issue, where nodejs has not yet actually set the key at the time you try to read it with php? How and _when_ are these two interacting?

Comment: I'm not trying to read data at the same time. When I get the same key in node js I get the data. I'm not able to read any of the keys set by node-js memcached-promisify when I try to read it using php memcache

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: I'd probably connect to the memcached service on the command line and list what keys are in there, in case they're not being stored the way you expect. Not sure if there's a better client, but years ago I remember doing that over telnet. e.g. http://www.alphadevx.com/a/90-Accessing-Memcached-from-the-command-line

Comment: yea I tried it over telnet. I'm able to read keys set using nodejs memcached through telnet but not able to read keys set by nodejs memcached-promosify through telnet

Comment: Well that narrows it a bit. Maybe it's using a different prefix or just not working at all.